# How to translate these logical addresses into physical addresses?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

Given that:

```
Logical addresss space=64
bits Physical address space=32 
bits Page size=4K
```

How will the logical addresses 20, 4100 and 8300 be mapped to physical address for the following page table?

[image]

Comment: It's not "here's my homework assignment, do it for me", it's "Here's what I have to answer, I've done this, but I can't get further because I don't understand that, my reasoning is such, where am I going wrong?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model, the page table entry is

```
  address DIV page-size
```

the offset is

```
  address MOD page-size
```

I don't know if your addresses are hex or decimal. I will assume hex.

For your first example--20

```
page table entry = 0
page offset = 20
```

Your page table entry 0 maps to page frame 2 = 2 x page-size = 8K

Logical address 20 is then physical address 8K + 20.

Use the same process for the rest.